# Sonicwall 3500 (Creating VLANS for usage of multiple SSID)

Tags: networking, vlan, ssid

I have an issue here.

Here is my setup:

- X0 - STAFF network |
- X2 - AGENT network |
- X4 - Wireless AP (for multiple SSID)

Okay, basically I'm going to set up the wireless AP to be broadcasting 2 SSID, STAFF-WIFI and AGENT WIFI. When connected to STAFF-WIFI, the users will be connected to the STAFF network, while connected to the AGENT WIFI, the users will be connected to the AGENT network.

Can someone explain in details how to go about setting up this configuration?

Comment: anyone to help on it please? :) quite urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create VLAN (Sub-interface) under Network --> Interface and create 2 SSID profiles under Sonicpoint --> VAP / Wireless --> VAP. Assign or tag them on the Sonicpoint and this should work.

Here is the [KB](https://support.software.dell.com/sonicwall-tz-series/kb/sw8470) as reference.